# Can't call function with modifier from another contract even if the owner himself calls

Tags: solidity, ethereum-wallet-dapp, modifiers

So I have multiple contracts that use the same modifier.

```
contract Token is ERC20Basic {

using SafeMath for uint256;

mapping(address => uint256) balances;

Owned private owned;

/// @dev `owner` is the only address that can call a function with this
/// modifier
modifier onlyOwner() {
    require(msg.sender == owned.getOwner());
    _;
}

function Token(address _owned) {

  owned = Owned(_owned);

}

function changeOwnerContract(address _owned) onlyOwner {

  owned = Owned(_owned);

}


function transfer(address _to, uint256 _value) public returns (bool) {

require(_to != address(0));

balances[msg.sender] = balances[msg.sender].sub(_value);
balances[_to] = balances[_to].add(_value);
Transfer(msg.sender, _to, _value);
return true;

}

 /**
 * @dev Gets the balance of the specified address.
 * @param _owner The address to query the the balance of.
 * @return An uint256 representing the amount owned by the passed address.
 */
function balanceOf(address _owner) public constant returns (uint256 balance) {
return balances[_owner];
}

function increaseTotal(uint256 _amount) public onlyOwner {

totalSupply = totalSupply.add(_amount);

}

function addToBalance(address _to, uint256 _amount) public onlyOwner {

balances[_to] = balances[_to].add(_amount);

}

}
```

And the second one:

```
contract TokenController {

Token private token;

Owned private owned;

event Mint(address indexed to, uint256 amount);

/// @dev `owner` is the only address that can call a function with this
/// modifier
modifier onlyOwner() {
    require(msg.sender == owned.getOwner());
    _;
}

function TokenController(address _sapien, address _owned) {

    token = token(_sapien);
    owned = Owned(_owned);

}

function changeBasicToken(address _sapien) onlyOwner {

    token = Token(_sapien);

}

function changeOwnerContract(address _owned) onlyOwner {

    owned = Owned(_owned);

}


function mint(address _to, uint256 _amount) onlyOwner returns (bool) {
    token.increaseTotal(_amount);
    token.addToBalance(_to, _amount);
    Mint(_to, _amount);
    return true;
}

}
```

Here is the Owned contract:

```
contract Owned {

address private owner;

/// @notice The Constructor assigns the message sender to be `owner`
function Owned() {
    owner = msg.sender;
}

address private newOwner;

/// @notice `owner` can step down and assign some other address to this role
/// @param _newOwner The address of the new owner. 0x0 can be used to create
///  an unowned neutral vault, however that cannot be undone
function changeOwner(address _newOwner) {

    if (msg.sender != owner)
        revert();

    newOwner = _newOwner;

}

function getOwner() public returns (address) {

    return owner;

}


function acceptOwnership() {
    if (msg.sender == newOwner) {
        owner = newOwner;
        newOwner = 0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000;
    }
}
}
```

If I try to deploy on Mist (all contracts from the same address) and then call "mint" from TokenController, I get an error saying that the function can't be executed. If I don't put onlyOwner in Token at "increaseTotal" and "addToBalance", it works. But it should also work if I have the modifier there, because I basically call from the same address that deployed Owned, Token and TokenController....

Do you know why it doesn't work?

Comment: Just to confirm - you are setting the _owned parameter of each correctly, right? Also, have you stepped through the transaction to see where it's failing?

Comment: @K.Fichter yes I tried multiple times and put the correct address of the Owned contract; it's failing on the check of onlyOwner on increaseTotal and addToBalance

Btw, I deploy from win 64

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that calling another contract changes `msg.sender`.

Let's say we have two contracts

```
contract A {
  B b;
  function foo() {
    // Here msg.sender is owner
    b.bar();
  }
}

contract B {
  function bar() { 
    // Here msg.sender is A
  }
}
```

If you execute a transaction `A.foo({ from: owner })`. Then inside `A.foo()` call we have `msg.sender` is equal to `owner`.

Now contract `A` calls function `bar` from contract `B`. Inside `B.bar()` we have `msg.sender` is equal to address of `A`.

Comment: Genius. Can't think that I missed that. Thank you!